# Are there any good hierarchial controls for web sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, controls

I want to generate an hierarchical data representation, more like a family tree rather than the typical tree view.

Something like this
[image]

Are there any solutions out there to accomplish this? Preferably in .NET but I am considering any solution that this available.

I have my hierarchical datasource, hopefully, I can just feed it into the constructor for this control and have it render on my site. A google and stack exchange search yielded nothing substantive.

Comment: Why is the tree you show us "not typical" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is the standard.  There are [bindings for programming languages](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php), as well as GUI editors, etc.